# Multi-module Maven project, need example how to build children modules using a common sibling module without duplicating the common

Tags: maven

Multi module Maven project duplicating contents of the common child fat JAR in all other children fat JARs using `maven-shade-plugin`.

I have a multi-module Maven project which builds several fat JARs. One child module builds a fat `common` JAR with its code and all its dependencies. That JAR is a dependency to all the other child `application` modules.

How do I build the `application` fat JARs with their code and additional dependencies without it including the contents of `common` JAR and it's dependencies. I expect to always reference the `common` JAR and one or more of the `application` JARs in my runtime but I don't want all the `application` JARs to duplicate what's in `common` JAR.

I've tried using `<artifactSet>` in root `maven-shade-plugin` and exclude the dependencies used in the `common` JAR, but that seems awfully cumbersome to manage that list and make sure it doesn't interfere with excluding any additional `application` module dependencies.

I've tried using `<scope>provided` for the `common` in the dependency list for the `application` modules, but that seems to only remove the `common` code, not it's dependencies.

I've thought about using profiles to build `common` one way and the `application`s a different way, but not sure how to do that.

Root POM:

- list of modules (`common`, `appA`, `appB`)
- list of common dependencies
- plugin `maven-shade-plugin`

Common child POM:

- list of dependencies

Application child POM:

- list of dependencies including `common.jar` and any "new" dependencies

I want `common.jar` to have all its code plus dependencies.

I want all other JARs to have their own code and any additional dependencies but with NO duplication of what's in `common.jar`.

Is there a simple solution?